# Let py know that (input1) == (input2)

Tags: python, calculator

I want to let my script stop, first I ask when I want to stop it:

`length = input("how many times " + str(num1) + str(" do you want to see?"))`
(E.G. I say ‘3’ the length should be 3)
Then I want to ‘ask’ if length is the same as where it must be when it should finish:
`if length == times` (times is where my script is ATM)
This doesn’t work, but if I set times to a number it does work…
Even when I print both of them (`print (times, length)`) it shows the same (3, 3) in my console, but it doesn’t do something… this is my script:

```
length = input("how many times " + str(num1) + str(" do you want to see?"))
 print("starting!")
 time.sleep(2)
 ORnum1 = num1
 times = 1
 while CalcMeth == "repeat":
  if C == "Yes":
     print(times, "times", ORnum1, "=", num1)
     num1 = num1 + ORnum1
     if length == times:
       C = "no"
       print("Reached End, stopping.")
     else:
       time.sleep(num2)
     times = times + 1
  elif C == "no":
   time.sleep(2)
   print ("stopped!")
   sys.exit()
```

Comment: `length = int(input())`, `input` give `str` type as return

Comment: Sahasrara62, tysm! It works, i was trying almost everything for 2 hours straight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if length == times:
```

here in your code length is in str and times is in integer.

```
length = int(input("how many times " + str(num1) +" do you want to see?))
```

Comment: By "input", you mean "integer".  And you don't need to call `str` on the second part; it's obviously already a string.

Comment: I missed than one out thanks for correction